# JetBrains IDEs - limit the length of argument name tooltips

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

Is it possible to limit the length of argument tooltips? Either prohibit long tooltips from displaying, or cut them after a certain amount of characters.

I do not want to switch them off completely, it's just sometimes that a monstrosity like this pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41450) which should be addressed in 2020.1 EAP builds.